# Jupyter notebook file explorer search bar

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

Does anyone know of a way to add a file explorer widget to my html file explorer when my jupyter folder opens up?

I can do ctrl + f like any html table but that's not quite as convenient as filtering.

I found ipyfilechooser, but that seems to create widgets inside of notebooks. I want one on the html explorer page.

Here is a mock up of what I am thinking:
[image]